# How to get file contents from a specific file name in directory?

Tags: php, parsing, readfile, glob

I've created a PHP script that pulls the extension '.mov' into the script and then parses the data. But the problem is, is that I have a directory with a bunch of .mov files, and the script is pulling the last one only.

In other words, I have a directory with "Keating651.mov" "NickSHC809.mov" "Vill230.mov" and more... Can I change my code to have it pull from a directory and pull the file that matches "NickSHC809"... then run the script? And if I change it to pull "Keating651" at a later time, it only pulls that file?

```
foreach (glob('*.mov') as $filename){
    $theData = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
}

$string = $theData;
$titles = explode("\n", $string);

function getInfo($string){
    $Ratings = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NR', 'XXX'];
    $split = preg_split("/\"(.+)\"/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
    if(count($split) == 3){ 
        preg_match("/(".implode("|", $Ratings).")\s/", $split[0], $matches);
        $rating = $matches[0];
        return ["title" => $split[1], "rating" => $rating];
    }
    return false;
}


$infolist = array();
foreach($titles as $title){
    $info = getInfo($title);
    if($info !== false){
    $infolist[] = $info;
    }
}

usort($infolist, "infosort");

function infosort($lhs,$rhs) {
  return strcmp($lhs['rating'], $rhs['rating']);
}

foreach ($infolist as $info) {
        echo "<div style ='margin-bottom: 3px; text-align: center;
          font:13px Verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;color:green;'> 
           {$info["title"]} : {$info["rating"]}</div>";
}

echo "<div style='text-align:center; margin-top: 20px;'><img src='shclogo.png'
alt='Logo' width='200' height='133'/></div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question. You just want the content of that one specific file, and then manually change the file to get? Then you could just change this

```
foreach (glob('*.mov') as $filename){
  $theData = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
}
```

To

```
$theData = file_get_contents("NickSHC809.mov") or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment, try

```
$matchedFiles = array();
foreach (glob('*.mov') as $filename){
  if (preg_match("/^(NickSHC809|Keating651)/i",$filename))
    $matchedFiles[] = $filename;
}
$useFile = reset($matchedFiles); // If you know there's just one file, otherwise do something to select the correct one
$theData = file_get_contents($useFile) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
```

Comment: I'd like to have the script pull the data only if it matches the correct prefix, like "NickSHC809" from the directory, because sometimes the prefix might have extra added words like "NickSHC809_test"

Comment: Is it always just one file, and always a .mov?

Comment: your edit is exactly what I was looking for. Adding the file prefix to the glob(*.mov) works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, edited it again, so you can add more prefixes. Is it still usable.